# Integral using the Riemann Sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Here I have a question to to calculate $$\int_{0}^{2}e^{x}dx$$ using Riemann sums. I got to the part where $$\int_{0}^{2}e^{x}dx=\lim....(e^{\frac{2i}{n}})\frac{2}{n}=\lim....(e^{\frac{2(\frac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r})}{n}})\frac{2}{n}$$
What should I do now? Can I expand this equation further? It doesnt seem like it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: shouldn't it be $\lim(e^{2/n}+e^{4/n}+\cdots+e^{2(n-1)/n})\dfrac2n=\dfrac{e^{2/n}-e^{2}}{1-e^{2/n}}\dfrac2n$?

Comment: yes, i made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, so we are partitioning $[0,2]$ into $n$ equal pieces each of length $\frac{2}{n}$. In particular:

$$x_i = 0+\frac{2i}{n} = \frac{2i}{n}$$

Then, we pick our evaluation set $T = \{x_i: i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}\}$. So, consider the Riemann Sum:

$$R(f,P,T) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i) \Delta x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{\frac{2i}{n}} \frac{2}{n}$$

Observe that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(e^{\frac{2}{n}} \right)^i$ is a geometric sum with common ratio $e^{\frac{2}{n}}$. So, we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(e^{\frac{2}{n}} \right)^i = \frac{1-\left(e^{\frac{2}{n}}\right)^{n+1}}{1-e^{\frac{2}{n}}}$$

Observe that the numerator of this expression simplifies to $1-e^{2+\frac{2}{n}}$. It is easy to see that this expression goes to $1-e^2$ as $n \to \infty$. Then, study the expression:

$$\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{1-e^{\frac{2}{n}}}$$

It is relatively easy to see that as $n \to \infty$, this expression goes to $-1$ (try proving this). So, it is the case that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} R(f,P,T) = e^2-1$$

and we are done. Now, alternatively, if you don't want to go that route with it, then there's a faster way to do the problem without having to do this sort of gymnastics.

Since $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous on $[0,2]$, it is Riemann Integrable there. Let $P = \{0 = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_{n-1} < x_n = 2\}$ be any partition of $[0,2]$. Since $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous and differentiable on every interval of $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\forall i: \exists t_i \in (x_{i-1},x_i): e^{t_i} = \frac{e^{x_i}-e^{x_{i-1}}}{\Delta x_i}$$

This is just a consequence of the MVT. Then, pick $T = \{t_i: i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}\}$ as your evaluation set and compute the Riemann Sum:

$$R(f,P,T) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(t_i) \Delta x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(e^{x_i}-e^{x_{i-1}} \right) = e^2-e^0 = e^2-1$$

where we have made use of the fact that we have a telescoping sum. This approach is nice because it actually generalizes and gives us a pretty neat proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus :D

Comment: but how did you arrive at $e^{2}-1$? I got $\frac{1-2e^{2}}{1-e^{\frac{2}{n}}}(\frac{2}{n})$ and don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: You calculate your finite sum incorrectly. Like, that expression for the finite sum seems to be incorrect. Try  computing it again but use algebra to do it instead. So, let:

$$S = 1+r+r^2+\ldots+r^{n-1}$$

$$rS = r+r^2+r^3+\ldots+r^n = S-1+r^n$$

$$S = \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

where $r \neq 1$. Now, do the same thing with the geometric series you have and calculate its sum that way. It's easier to work through the algebra in this rather than to just plug things into a formula.

Comment: ok thanks =)  =D (emoji for minimum characters in a comment)

Comment: Haha sure, no problem :D

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_0^2e^xdx&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac2{n}e^{2i/n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{n}\left(\frac{e^{2}-1}{e^{2/n}-1}\right)\\
&=e^2-1.
\end{align}

Comment: could you explain a bit more like$\frac{1-2e^{2}}{1-e^{\frac{2}{n}}}(\frac{2}{n})$ and don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Use that $\lim_{x\to0}(e^x-1)/x=1$.